# I can't compare a user input and a list of Hockey Players

Tags: vba, excel

[Picture of Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XX3EP.png)

```
Private Sub NextR_Click()
    Dim a As Integer
    If Goalie1.Value = "" Or Goalie2.Value = "" Then
        MsgBox "Please make sure that you have a goalie entered for both teams and that the name is spelled correctly."
    Else
        For a = 3 To 500
            If Goalie1.Value = Sheets("Players").Cells(a, 9) Then
                Sheets("Game").Range("C5").Value = Cells(a, 6)
                Sheets("Game").Range("D5").Value = Cells(a, 7)
                Sheets("Game").Range("E5").Value = Cells(a, 8)
            Else
                Sheets("Game").Range("C5").Value = 5
            End If
        Next a
        For a = 3 To 500
            If Sheets("Players").Cells(a, 9).Value = Goalie2.Value Then
                Sheets("Game").Range("I5").Value = Cells(a, 6)
                Sheets("Game").Range("J5").Value = Cells(a, 7)
                Sheets("Game").Range("K5").Value = Cells(a, 8)
            Else
                Sheets("Game").Range("I5").Value = 10
            End If
        Next a

    End If
End Sub
```

I have 2 sheets, one listed as "Game", and one listed as "Players". The "Players" sheet has a list of hockey goalies and players, they players have stats for games played, shots, and position, the goalies have shots against, and shots saved. I have the user input the goalie name in a user form input box and compare it to all of the names in the Goalie list. For some reason, the program is still setting my goalie names to 5 and 10. Can you help me understand why this is happening.

Comment: Text is notoriously hard to compare, especially names.  One typo or extra space will cause it to not be equal.  Look into using drop downs that the user can select, that way the spelling is constant.

Comment: Also add sheet references to all your ranges.

Answer (score 0):

The code you have runs through all of rows 3 to 500 regardless of whether you find a match for the goalie or not. It doesn't stop when you find the right goalie.

You need to exit the `For` loop once you have found the correct row. Use an [Exit For statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251570.aspx), like this:

```
For a = 3 To 500
    If Goalie1.Value = Sheets("Players").Cells(a, 9) Then
        Sheets("Game").Range("C5").Value = Cells(a, 6)
        Sheets("Game").Range("D5").Value = Cells(a, 7)
        Sheets("Game").Range("E5").Value = Cells(a, 8)
        Exit For
    Else
        Sheets("Game").Range("C5").Value = 5
    End If
Next a
```